# Vary legend properties for different data in seaborn scatterplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have created a seaborn scatterplot for a dataset, where I set the sizes parameter to one column, and the hue parameter to another. Now the hue parameter only consists of five different values and is supposed to help classifying my data, while the sizes parameter consists of a lot more to represent actual numeric data. In this current data set, my hue values only consist of 0, 2, and 4, but in the "brief" legend option, the legend labels are not synchronized to that, which is very confusing. In the "full" legend option, the hue-labels are correct, but the size-labels are way too many. Therefore I would like to display the full legend for my hue parameter, but only a brief legend for the sizes parameter, because it consists of lots of unique values.

How the overcrowded "full" legend looks

[image]

The "brief" legend that is confusingly labeled

[image]

Edit: I edited some code in that demonstrates the issue for a random dataset. To specify my question again, I want the "shape" parameters to get fully depicted on the legend, while the "size" parameters have to be shortened (equivalent to the legend setting "brief").

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x_condition=np.arange(0,20,1)
y_condition=np.arange(0,20,1)
size=np.random.randint(0,200,20)

# I haven't made a random distribution here, because I wanted to make sure it contains at least one of each [0,2,4]
shape=[0,2,0,4]*5

df=pd.DataFrame({"x_condition":x_condition,"y_condition":y_condition,"size":size,"shape":shape})

sns.scatterplot("x_condition", "y_condition", hue="shape", size="size", data=df, palette="coolwarm", legend="brief")
plt.show()

sns.scatterplot("x_condition", "y_condition", hue="shape", size="size", data=df, palette="coolwarm", legend="full")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share a minimum working example of the code you've got so far :)

Comment: Okay, I have added a random dataset.